# What is wrong with my replace string with another string or character using linked list

Tags: c, string

I have a linked list with many chars which I input from my input (`what is the weather today?`), to be replaced with another string (for example `what` replaced with `how`, so I get `how is the weather today?`).

But if the given words are right next to each other for example `whatwhat`, it will change to `howwhat`, disregarding the second part.

I think the problem is in the compare function, but I have no clue how to fix it, but the logic of replace should go like this:

If the words from my list and the needed word are the same, then proceed to iterate to the position where the next node of the word that should be changed (unwanted word) should be (pretty much the end of the word), then I create a new linked list with character with the wanted word, and connect temp to the start of the list and the next of the list to the position where the next character of the word that needs to be changed (unwanted word), which I found in the first loop.

Also don't roast my `input()` function, I know it is unsafe I just want to see what unsafe means with my own eyes, while I still have nothing to lose.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct node { 
    int value_c;
    struct node *next_c;
    struct node *prev_c;
};

typedef struct node string;

int compare(string *head, char *word) {
    int counter = 0;
    string *temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        if (temp->value_c == word[i]) {
            temp = temp->next_c;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == strlen(word))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void print_c(string *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%c", head->value_c);
        head = head->next_c;
    }
}

void append_c(string **head, char thing) {
    string *newNode = (string *)malloc(sizeof(string));

    newNode->value_c = thing;
    newNode->next_c = NULL;
    
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newNode;
        newNode->prev_c = NULL;
        return;
    }
    
    string *temp = *head;

    while (temp->next_c != NULL)
        temp = temp->next_c;

    temp->next_c = newNode;
    newNode->prev_c = temp;
}

string *replace_all1(string *head, char *what, char *with_what) {
    string *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", temp->value_c);
        if (compare(temp, what) == 1) {
            printf("%i ", 1); 
            printf("%c ", temp->value_c);
            string *new = temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(what) - 1; i++) {
                new = new->next_c;
            }
            string *word = NULL;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(with_what); i++) {
                append_c(&word, with_what[i]);
            }

            string *word_temp = word;
            while (word_temp->next_c != NULL) {
                word_temp = word_temp->next_c;
            }

            word_temp->next_c = new->next_c;
            if (temp->prev_c != NULL) {
                temp->prev_c->next_c = word;
            } else {
                head = word;
                print_c(head);
                temp = word;
                print_c(temp);
                word->prev_c = NULL;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next_c;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return head;
}

string *String(char *str) {
    string *st = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        append_c(&st, str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return st;
}

string *input() {
    char *a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", a); //maximum of 1408
    string *stri = String(a);
    return stri;
    free(a);
}

int main() {
    string *list = NULL;

    string *big_boy_string = input();
    //printf("%c", big_boy_string->value_c);
    //print_c(big_boy_string);
    //printf("\n");
    //printf("%i", compare(big_boy_string, "what"));
    //printf("%i ", len(big_boy_string));

    //printf("\n");
    //print_c(slice(big_boy_string, 1, 10));
    //print_c(replace(big_boy_string, 'h', 'a'));
    //printf("\n");
    //print_c(reverse(big_boy_string));
    print_c(replace_all1(big_boy_string, "a", "b"));
    //getline();
}
```

Comment: C++ and C are different languages. This looks like C, so please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: I recommend you start over. and then reimplement the code a ***very*** small piece at a time. Pieces that are small enough to be very easy to test and debug. Also when it comes to things like lists, I also recommend you try to "perform" all operations using pencil and paper first. Draw a simple linked list, using squares for nodes and arrows for all pointers. Erase and redraw the arrows as you modify them to solve the problem (adding, removing, etc.).

Comment: By the way: `scanf("%[^\n]",a)`? The variable `a` points to an array of 
***one single*** character. It can fit the string terminator, and *only* the string terminator. Or any other single character, but then it's just a single character and not a string. Why are you even using dynamic allocation here? Why not a plain array? Like `char a[256];`? At least that will remove the memory leak you have (since you call `free` *after* you return from the function). Since the `scanf` call will write out of bounds of the memory, you will have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)); 
scanf("%[^\n]",a); //maximum of 1408
```

The first statement allocates memory for just 1 byte. So the maximum is not 1408, but 1. It can store a single `char`, or the null-terminator if it's a string, but no more.

Next, `scanf()` will write to out of bounds memory, and invoke undefined behaviour. The subsequent functions all depend on this undefined behaviour, so I'm not going to look at them.

But then, you've a memory leak in the same function.

```
return stri;
free(a);
```

You `return` before freeing the allocated memory. The call to `free()` is never executed.

The return value of `malloc()` is also ignored. Code risks undefined behaviour if the subsequent dereferences are on a `NULL` pointer.

Aside: The cast is meaningless and may hide a bug. `malloc()` and family returns a `void *` that is implicitly converted to the right type.

---

> Re: Also don't roast my input() function, I know its unsafe I just
> want to see what unsafe means with my own eyes.

If you are already aware of this, then you shouldn't be asking why your code doesn't work. You are relying on undefined behaviour (playing with fire).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to look further than the `input` function: it has undefined behavior or the worst kind because you attempt to read the input string into a very small array, allocated for a single byte.  You must fix this first.  Since you know the maximum length of your input string, you can use this:

```
string *input(void) {
    char a[1409];
    if (scanf("%1408[^\n]", a) != 1) { //maximum of 1408
        // invalid or missing input
        return NULL;
    }
    scanf(%*[^\n]");  // consume any remaining characters on the input line
    scanf(%*1[\n]");  // consume the newline if present
    return String(a);
}
```

Here is an alternative using `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` which is quite tricky and error prone:

```
string *input(void) {
    char a[1409];
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (i + 1 < sizeof(a))
            a[i++] = (char)c;
    }
    if (c == EOF && i == 0) {
        /* end of file without any input */
        return NULL;
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
    return String(a);
}
```

The compare function is incorrect: it should return false as soon as the comparison fails and it must test for the end of string (`temp == NULL`):

```
int compare(const string *head, const char *word) {
    string *temp = head;
    for (size_t i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (temp == NULL || temp->value_c != word[i])
            return 0;
        temp = temp->next_c;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The `replace_all1()` function has problems too:

- `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(what) - 1; i++)` will cause undefined behavior if `what` is an empty string because `strlen(what) - 1` is unsigned with the value `SIZE_MAX` in this case, causing the loop to proceed for a very long time, well beyond the end of the list pointed to by `new`.
- `while (word_temp->next_c != NULL)` will cause a undefined behavior if the replaced word is empty as `word_temp` will be `NULL`.
- once you replace the sublist, you do not update `temp` correctly to point to the node after the replaced one, which you could achieve by setting `temp` to `word_temp`.
- the function does not free the replaced sublist.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int value_c;
    struct node *next_c;
    struct node *prev_c;
};

typedef struct node string;

void string_append_char(string **head, int c) {
    string *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->value_c = c;
    node->next_c = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        node->prev_c = NULL;
        *head = node;
    } else {
        string *temp = *head;

        while (temp->next_c != NULL)
            temp = temp->next_c;

        node->prev_c = temp;
        temp->next_c = node;
    }
}

string *string_new(const char *str) {
    string *st = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        string_append_char(&st, str[i]);
    }
    return st;
}

string *string_input(const char *prompt) {
    string *st = NULL;
    int c;

    if (prompt) {
        printf("%s", prompt);
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        string_append_char(&st, c);
    }
    return st;
}

void string_print(const char *before, const string *head, const char *after) {
    printf("%s", before);
    while (head != NULL) {
        putchar(head->value_c);
        head = head->next_c;
    }
    printf("%s", after);
}

void string_free(string *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        string *next = head->next_c;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

int string_compare(const string *head, const char *word) {
    const string *temp = head;
    for (size_t i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (temp == NULL || temp->value_c != word[i])
            return 0;
        temp = temp->next_c;
    }
    return 1;
}

int string_replace(string **head, const char *what, const char *with_what) {
    int count = 0;

    if (*what == '\0')
        return 0;

    string *temp = *head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (string_compare(temp, what)) {
            count++;
            // locate the last node of the substring
            string *temp_end = temp;
            for (size_t i = 0; what[i + 1] != '\0'; i++) {
                temp_end = temp_end->next_c;
            }
            string *next = temp_end->next_c;
            if (*with_what == '\0') {
                // just delete the substring
                if (temp->prev_c != NULL) {
                    temp->prev_c->next_c = next;
                } else {
                    *head = next;
                }
                if (next) {
                    next->prev_c = temp->prev_c;
                }
            } else {
                // create a string from the replacement
                string *word = string_new(with_what);
                // locate the last node of the new substring
                string *word_end = word;
                while (word_end->next_c != NULL) {
                    word_end = word_end->next_c;
                }
                word->prev_c = temp->prev_c;
                if (temp->prev_c != NULL) {
                    temp->prev_c->next_c = word;
                } else {
                    *head = word;
                }
                word_end->next_c = next;
                if (next) {
                    next->prev_c = word_end;
                }
            }
            temp_end->next_c = NULL;
            string_free(temp);
            temp = next;
        } else {
            temp = temp->next_c;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    string *list = string_input("enter string: ");
    string_print("input: ", list, "\n");
    printf("replacing 'what' to 'how': %d matches\n", string_replace(&list, "what", "how"));
    string_print("rep1: ", list, "\n");
    printf("replacing 'a' to 'b': %d matches\n", string_replace(&list, "a", "b"));
    string_print("rep2: ", list, "\n");
    printf("deleting 'h': %d matches\n", string_replace(&list, "h", ""));
    string_print("rep3: ", list, "\n");
    string_free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
enter string: what is the weather today?
input: what is the weather today?
replacing 'what' to 'how': 1 matches
rep1: how is the weather today?
replacing 'a' to 'b': 2 matches
rep2: how is the webther todby?
deleting 'h': 3 matches
rep3: ow is te webter todby?
```